# User and Session info from within JAVA UDF Oracle 11g

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I wish to get user info just like provided by

```
SELECT SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'SESSION_USER') FROM DUAL;
```

and

```
SELECT SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'OS_USER') FROM DUAL;
```

inside a JAVA UDF for Oracle 11g without making a JDBC connection and running these queries to query from DUAL.

I tried `System.getProperty("user.name")` to read the current OS_user through jvm but I think we are not allowed to fetch information outside the database environment.

More generically, problem statement is to fetch information about the user who has logged into database and using that java UDF (where we need to determine these information) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution to above problem by using the `"jdbc:default:connection"` which is an internal connection maintained by database itself which is always available. Notice I did not do `conn.close();` in the end because this is a shared stream which once closed is closed for all database clients.

```
public static String doSQL() throws SQLException {
    String result = new String();
    String q1 = "SELECT SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','SESSION_USER') FROM DUAL";
    Connection conn =
            DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:default:connection");
    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(
            q1
    );
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
    while (rs.next())
        result = rs.getString(1);
    return "my udf says"+result;
}
```